# Angular js and ui bootstrap radio buttons Hebrew letters

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, hebrew

When setting Hebrew letters in an array and using this array to create radio buttons in angularjs ui bootstrap, I get this message in console for each value:

```
   Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 0-0 [ב] in expression [בניברק].
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unexpected%20next%20character%20&p1=s%200-0%20%5B%D7%91%5D&p2=%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%A7
        at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js:78:12
        at Lexer.throwError (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js:10015:11)
        at Lexer.lex (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js:9969:16)
        at Parser.parse (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js:10199:30)
        at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js:11048:37
        at Scope.$eval (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js:12412:16)
        at ngModelCtrl.$render (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.js:363:100)
        at Object.ngModelWatch (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js:17342:14)
        at Scope.$digest (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js:12243:40)
        at Scope.$apply (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js:12516:24)
```

You can see this in the following plunker:
    http://plnkr.co/edit/Y6AkNrd53ODMwBwUV7ru?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Its seems that there isnt any problem with the Hebrew.

I changed your plunker and changed the label that contain the ng-repeat to div, and set the ng-model of the input to br (because it was set to undefined variable).
now its working well without errors.

```
You can see the plunker at [http://plnkr.co/edit/etuEopNOllXpzJbl9qXL?p=preview][1]
```